# Parse Server Cloud Code - Checking Username

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I just switched from parse to parse server with AWS and Mongolab. Currently I try to write some verifications to the cloud part in main.js in the server.

After adding the code below, which is a verification before saving to the class "posts". I want it to check if the username of the logged in user is equal to a specified value. However, after adding this I even con not login to my app with any of my users I used to log in. It says wrong password or username.

```
  Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('posts', function (req, res) {

  var uname = 'xxxxx';

   var user = Parse.User.current();
  user.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
  uname = fetchedUser.getUsername();    
   }, 
  );

  if (uname != 'michael') {
   res.error('This user is not allowed');

   } else {
   res.success();
   }

   });
```

I also use the cloud code below but it is working fine:

```
 Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('tweets', function (req, res) {

 if (req.object.get('name') != 'jeniffer') {
 res.error('This user is not allowed');

 } else {
   res.success();
 }

 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main issues with the code. First, Parse.User.current() cannot be used with `parse-server` and second, the promises syntax are a little wrong. Try this instead:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('posts', function (req, res) {
  req.user.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
    var uname = fetchedUser.getUsername();
    if (uname !== 'michael') {
      res.error('This user is not allowed');
    } else {
      res.success();
    }
  }, function(err) {
    res.error(err);
  });
});
```

Also, `posts` sounds like a strange collection name. Should probably be `Post`.